# document.getElementById("id"); is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a js. program to show a random number from 1 to whatever number that is entered in an `<input/>` whenever the "GENERATE" button is pressed.

The problem is that when I press the "GENERATE" button, It returns "NaN".

Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
        <script src='script.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

  <br/>
  <center>
  <div><button onclick="generate()" title="generate random 
  number">GENERATE</button> <p class="space" id="space"></p> </div>

  <input id="number" type="number" name="contestants" min="1" 
  placeholder="max">

  </center>


</body>
```

```
var max = document.getElementById("number");

function generate(){

document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;

}
```

The `<p class="space" id="space"></p>` is the final random number that shows up just underneath the "GENERATE" button.

Please help; I am just starting out on this html, css, and JavaScript thing, so it would be nice if I could get this figured out.

```js
var max = document.getElementById("number");

function generate(max) {

  document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.space {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='script.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <br/>
  <center>
    <div><button onclick="generate()" title="generate random number">GENERATE</button>
      <p class="space" id="space"></p>
    </div>

    <input id="number" type="number" name="contestants" min="1" placeholder="max">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to get the input's value. You should also give your script the `defer` tag.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * max.value) + 1` is all you need!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're missing the ".value" on the max variable try

```
var max = document.getElementById("number").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code var max = document.geElementBtId("number").value

Inside your generate method and remove parameter max from generate method.

Comment: doesn't make any difference. `var max = document.geElementById("number")` doesn't output the value

Comment: Yes need to add value after get the element but as generate method used event handler so can be used as like my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Use value function to get actual value from element

Change `Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumber.value) + 1`

```js
function generate(maxNumber) {
   var maxNumber = document.getElementById("number");  

  document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.space {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='script.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <br/>
  <center>
    <div><button onclick="generate()" title="generate random number">GENERATE</button>
      <p class="space" id="space"></p>
    </div>

    <input id="number" type="number" name="contestants" min="1" placeholder="max">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
```

**With**

```
document.getElementById("space").innerHTML =Math.floor(Math.random() * parseInt(max.value)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

move

> var max = document.getElementById("number").value;

into the **generate()** function because when the page loads it tries to fetch the value of input field which is null initially hence throw an error

```
function generate() {
        var max =document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
        // console.log(max);
        document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I got it working by adding `.value` to:                                                     
var max = document.getElementById("myNumber")---here---;                                             Also I `console.log(max);' like you added and the debug got it going.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use generate function like this :

```
    function generate(maxNumber) {
       var maxNumber = document.getElementById("number");  
       document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
```

In that this code : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) last argument give maximum limit of your random number.For example if your number between 0 to 10 then you have to write 
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).